# controller gets factory data before data is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple factory that looks like this

```
myApp.factory('eventFactory', function(){
    var events = [];

    return {
        getEvents : function(){
            return events;
        },
        setEvent : function(event){
            events.push(event);
        }
    }
});
```

and when my application loads I run a promise to load events from a remote server, when promise is returned I run: `$scope.eventFactory.setEvent(event);` to set these returned events to the event factory.

In my other controller I want to set these events to a `$scope` variable, so I inject the `eventFactory` and do this:

```
$scope.eventFactory = eventFactory;
$scope.events = $scope.eventFactory.getEvents();
```

problem is this also runs when application is first loaded, before the promise has returned my events, so my `events` array in my factory is empty, hence my `$scope.events` in my second controller is also empty, and it doesn't update when promise is returned.

How do I update `$scope.events` in my second controller when promise is returned in my first controller?

Comment: Could You post code of the second controller? Are You replacing array on `scope` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Resolve to load the Events , so that your app will get Data when its redy ... for Example

```
    $stateProvider.state('root', {
      resolve:{
         // Example using function with simple return value.        
         promiseObj:  function(eventFactory){
         // eventFactory returns a promise for the  data
        return eventFactory.getEvents();
     }
   })
```

And in your Controller inject the `promiseObj` to get the data,

```
    myApp.controller('yourCtrl',function($scope,promiseObj){
       $scope.events = promiseObj; // binding the data in promiseObj to $scope 
    });
```

for ngRoute

```
   $routeProvider
    .when("/root", {
      templateUrl: "yourView.html",
      controller: "yourController",
      resolve: {
         promiseObj:  function(eventFactory){
           return eventFactory.getEvents();
           }
      }        
   })
```

Comment: please elaborate, what is `$stateProvider` for example?

Comment: which module are you using for Routing ? . ng-route ?

Comment: I'm not, it's a single page application

Comment: Consider lazy load scenario, maybe user don't want to block route until data is resolved?